# Azure Active Directory to new Windows 2019 Server

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, office365, windows-server-2019

we have been using office 365 E3 for the past number of years.  we would like to configure a windows 2019 essentials server locally for file storage and a few shared applications (ie quickbooks multi-user).

is there a process to pull the user information from azure active directory to the local server?  any advice is greatly appreciated.

thank you!!

Comment: Do you have on-premise AD? If yes, you could export the users from Azure AD and import them into on-premise AD. There is no official  solution to sync users from the cloud to the local.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, you really want is to be able to grant admin rights to your Azure AD users and allow them to login to the server with their regular Azure AD credentials.

If yes, then most optimum way of doing is to have  on prem AD and have you user synced up from Azure AD to local AD. Azure AD Connect comes pretty handy in this scenario.

You can also take a look at Azure AD DS, Azure Active Directory Domain Services (Azure AD DS) provides managed domain services such as domain join, group policy, lightweight directory access protocol (LDAP), and Kerberos / NTLM authentication that is fully compatible with Windows Server Active Directory. You use these domain services without the need to deploy, manage, and patch domain controllers in the cloud. Azure AD DS integrates with your existing Azure AD tenant, which makes it possible for users to sign in using their existing credentials.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview

Check this link as well for additional reference:

https://serverfault.com/questions/808047/how-to-manage-on-premise-servers-using-azure-ad-credentials

Hope it helps.

Comment: i believe this is the solution:  https://www.slashadmin.co.uk/how-to-sync-an-existing-office365-tenant-into-a-new-active-directory-domain/